# change offset value for iphone with jquery

Tags: jquery, iphone, scroll

I am using the localScroll plugin. Which works great on the desktop but not so well on the iphone, it looks like it scrolls to the wrong section.

I'm using a init.js

```
    $.localScroll.hash({
    queue:false,
    duration:1000,
    offset: {top:-245, left:0}
});
```

And for the mobile init.js file I would like

```
    $.localScroll.hash({
    queue:false,
    duration:1000,
    offset: {top:0, left:0}
});
```

Can you have a mobile init.js file which would fire for iPhone and not for the desktop?

Or is there another way to have a change the offset value?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
var isiPhone = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null;
if ( isiPhone == true ) {
    $.localScroll.hash({
    queue:false,
    duration:1000,
    offset: {top:0, left:0}
    });

} else {

    $.localScroll.hash({
    queue:false,
    duration:1000,
    offset: {top:-245, left:0}
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I assume you can target the ipad as well. Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure, a quick update and it can be used to detect iPad, too: `var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;` Then similar comparison to address only iPad users :)